# How to read jira fields based on their name from CSV file

Tags: python, python-jira

I'm trying to read and update some fields based on issue number and field name from csv file.

Currently I've hard-coded the names and it looks like this

```py
from jira import JIRA
import csv
```

later i read csv file in which column 0 is issue number and column 1 is field name/ID

```
issue,fieldid
TEST-1,customfield_XXXX
```

```py
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
```

and in for loop i read issue by issue

```py
issue = jira.issue(f'{row[0]}')
```

and update field

```py
issue.update(fields={f'{row[1]}': issue.fields.customfield_XXXX + 'additionall text'})
```

in the last step I'd like to change `issue.fields.customfield_XXXX` to be generated based on the second column of the csv file  `row[1]` 
Something like `issue.fields.row[1]`

Any tips on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try accessing it using issue.fields[row[1]]?

Comment: @KevinMüller Yes, when i try to do this, i get an error ```TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable```